# Insert into Access junction table with VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have three tables:

**tblRejection**
RejectionID, Period, TescoYear, TescoWeek, RejectionDate, Packsize, TPNB, TPND, BatchCode, ProductID

**tblReason**
ReasonID, ReasonDesc, Quantity, CasesInspected, InspectedPacks, PercentageAffected, Display until

**tblRejectionReason**
RejectionReasonID (autonumber), RejectionID, ReasonID

The idea is that a rejection can be added and a reason for the rejection can be added.

The purpose of RejectionReason table is because a rejection can have more than reason for rejection.

I am simply trying to insert the IDs created in tblRejection and tblReason as the foreign key values from the respective primary key of each table.

testSQL1 and testSQL2 work fine. But testSQL3 does not insert the primary key values of the two tables as foreign key values into the linked table.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with testSQL3?

```
Dim testSQL1 As String
Dim testSQL2 As String
Dim testSQL3 As String

testSQL1 = "INSERT INTO tblRejection (period, tescoyear, tescoweek, rejectiondate, packsize, TPNB, TPND, batchcode, productID) VALUES ('x','xxxx','xx','xxxxx','xxxxx','xxxxxxx','xxxxxx','xxxxxx',1);"
testSQL2 = "INSERT INTO tblReason (reasondescription, quantity, casesinspected, inspectedpacks, affectedpacks, percentageaffected, displayuntil) VALUES ('zzzzzzz',20,100,50,20,'xxxx','xxxxxx');"

testSQL3 = "INSERT INTO tblRejectionReason (rejectionid, reasonid) " & _
            '"SELECT tblrejection.rejectionid, tblreason.reasonid " & _
            '"FROM tblReason " & _
            '"INNER JOIN (tblRejection INNER JOIN tblRejectionReason ON tblRejection.RejectionID = tblRejectionReason.RejectionID) " & _
            '"ON tblReason.ReasonID = tblRejectionReason.ReasonID;"        

Debug.Print testSQL1
DoCmd.RunSQL testSQL1
Me.Refresh

Debug.Print testSQL2
DoCmd.RunSQL testSQL2
Me.Refresh

Debug.Print testSQL3
DoCmd.RunSQL testSQL3
Me.Refresh`
```

Comment: Why use VBA and SQL instead of bound forms? Why SQL with static values?

Comment: I am using static values to test with first. I have a form that the user will fill in and ill replace the static values with values from the form via textboxes and combo boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JOINs make no sense - remove them. Just need `FROM tblReason, tblRejection`. This causes a Cartesian association of records. Every record of each table associates with every record of other table to produce every possible pairing of the ID fields.

Set rejectionID and reasonID fields in tblRejectionReason as compound index to prevent duplicate pairs.

Comment: What is the issue with this query?    

"INSERT INTO tblRejectionReason ( RejectionID, ReasonID ) " & _
                "SELECT tblRejection.RejectionID, tblReason.ReasonID " & _
                "FROM tblRejection, tblReason;"

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? If you want tblRejectionReason to have every possible pairing of ID fields from the other 2 tables, my suggestion will do that. Remove the JOINs and change the FROM as shown. The JOINs make no sense as there are no records in tblRejectionReason to join to and if there were, there would be no need to insert the ID's. Research Cartesian product query, start with https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-join-cartesian-join-self-join/

Comment: I'd like to accomplish this.

tblRejection
 RejectionID, Date
 1, 07/07/2021
 2, 07/07/2021
 3, 11/07/2021
 4, 11/07/2021
tblRejectionReason
 RejectionReasonID, RejectionID, ReasonID
 1, 1, 1
 2, 1, 2
 3, 3, 3
 4, 3, 4
tblReason
 ReasonID, ReasonComment, Quantity
 1, Issue found - colour (Level: 2), 65 
 2, Issue found - Chill damage (Level: 2), 90 
 3, Issue found - Rots and mould (Level: 3/4), 125  
4, Issue found - Rots (Level: 3&4), 108

Comment: A situtation where a rejection can have one or more reasons to be rejected.

I plan to get the user to fill in all information for ONE reason first.

Then create a search function to be able to add MORE reasons to an existing rejection.

Link to what I want to achieve: https://ibb.co/RY9YtVb

Comment: Doesn't change my comments nor suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. So based on my requirement, Im guessing that I would need to set the reasonID index to be unique and the rejectionID to contain dupes. Would you agree? Sorry Im struggling to understand this so I appreciate your feedback

Comment: If reasonID would be unique in tblRejectionReason then you would not need this table. Just put associated rejectionID in tblReason. Junction tables are only needed for many-to-many data relationships. Perhaps you need to research and gain better understanding of database relationships.

Comment: I think you are right. I seem to have overcooked this a bit. I will go and think the design. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

I went and re designed my database because I made it overly complex.

Now I simply have two tables with primary and foreign key and a form and subform.

The many to many was not needed.